# tapGesture not being executed

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have added a tapGesture to my UIImageView rDot. The problem is when I tap on rDot nothing happens and it doesn't print "It worked". rDot is in a stack view with other elements, I don't know if that has anything to do with it not working. rDot and redDot are two separate UIImageViews.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        rDot.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rdotimageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        rDot.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)                        
}

func rdotimageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        whiteD?.isHidden = true
        redDot?.isHidden = false
        print("It worked")
    }
```

Comment: Try this after adding `gesture`, might work for you: `view.bringSubview(toFront: rDot)`

Comment: try adding selector by `action: #selector(MyClass.rdotimageTapped(_:))`

Comment: @Santosh Thank you it is printing out, but now the images aren't becoming hidden or unhidden. Both of the images are on a different viewController.

Comment: Add `view.layoutIfNeeded()` after you hide them.

Comment: Please mark my below answer since the solution worked for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bring the `subView` to front since you have put the `imageView` within `stackView`. Sometimes the view hierarchy does not recognize the tapped `subviews`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    rDot.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rdotimageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    rDot.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer) 
    view.bringSubview(toFront: rDot)                
}
```